# Assembly into C

Tags: c, assembly

I need to convert assembly code to C code, and I am having a problem with those two lines:

```
 804842d:   c7 44 24 18 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x18(%esp)
 8048434:   00 
 8048435:   c7 44 24 1c 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x1c(%esp)
 804843c:   00
```

This is the assembly code I was given.

So in C I have created this part of the main function:

```
 int main(){
   int x, y;
   x=0;
   y=0;
  }
```

But when I convert this code to assembly I get:

```
804842d:    c7 44 24 1c 08 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x1c(%esp)
8048434:    00 
8048435:    c7 44 24 18 07 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x18(%esp)
804843c:    00
```

Why do I get the two addresses flipped in my assembly version (0x1c(%esp) and 0X18(%esp))? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: @DeadCicada would that be true even if optimizations were turned off?

Comment: Maybe try declaring `int y, x;` to get the reversed order of addresses?  Though as long as your consistent in translating one assembler address/offset to x and the other to y, it really won't matter very much...  One of the nice things about high level languages is not having to worry about such details.

Comment: Yes, already tried to switch the places when declaring. I get the same result. I am just worried that this swap will mess up the rest of the "translation" from assembly to C

Comment: This seems to be a pointless exercise. There's no reasonable way to coerce the compiler to place the variables at a particular location in the stack frame. Even if you could influence it somehow (without using inline assembly or something), the slightest change - even to compiler options - could result in a different layout by the compiler. The compiler is even free to decide to *not* put the locals on the stack frame at all (keeping them in registers), or to reuse a stack location for another local variable if it determines that the first var is no longer needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with others that this is an effort of doubtful sensibleness.

However, it is useful to be able to *properly understand* the generated assembly code, at least. The major catch here is that *on x86, stack grows downwards*. That means variables higher on the stack (assuming no optimization and delving into implementation-specific details, the variables declared later) have *lower* address than variables declared earlier.

With this in mind, it would make sense that address of **y** is `0x18(%esp)` while the address of **x** is `0x1c(%esp)`. To make things clearer for yourself, always try to fill the variables with different values.

Note that the stack growing downwards seems rather confusing, but back in the early days of Intel architecture it made sense - code and dynamically allocated data was being loaded at as low addresses as possible, while the stack was based at the top of the address space. This way, you would not have to make an explicit compromise about how much memory to reserve for stack and how much for heap - just as long as the sum of two would be below total address space size, they could share the address space nicely.

Comment: I agree with what you explain here, and I was trying to understand why the values of x and y get flipped once I convert back to assembly